Not able to select package manager while setting up turborepo project
enter image description here
When I use npx create-turbo@latest
it asks me what package manager I want to use then it shows me these four options but it says I don't have any of those installed. How do I install them, particularly npm. And that is the error it gives.
steps but these types of errors lowers my confidence, please help...
I tried updating npm globally and also uninstalling it and reinstalling it, but it didn't work
I am a beginner in programming,this might be a very silly issue which could be solved in very few

This error occurred because Node.js was installed using the Snap command. Snap isolates applications in containers, which can cause issues like npm not installed when running commands such as npx create-turbo@latest ./. Switching to NVM resolves these conflicts by allowing better integration of Node.js and npm with the development environment.
Step 1: Uninstall Node.js Installed via Snap
sudo snap remove node

Step 2: Install NVM (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash

Step 3: Load NVM into Your Shell Session
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

Step 4: Verify NVM Installation
nvm -v

Step 5: Install Node.js Using NVM
nvm install 20

This resolves the "npm not installed" error and provides better control over Node.js versions using NVM.
